# Result of R external script in T-SQL is badly rounded

Tags: r, t-sql, machine-learning, summary, sql-server-2017

I have data about the various costs (costs_q_active) and I need to use specially the `summary` function in R.
I use this statement in R:

```
mysummary <- cbind.data.frame(
S = c("Minimum", "1st Quartal", "Median", "Mean", "3rd Quarter", "Maximum")
, do.call(
    cbind
    , lapply(costs_q_active, summary)
    )
)
```

That give normal values like 24921.823444. But when I use this code in the T-SQL procedure `sp_execute_external_script`, the values are rounded to the first four digits but not to the whole number etc (so I get number 24920).

```
EXEC sp_execute_external_script @language =N'R', @script=N'
costs_q <- InputDataSet
colnames(costs_q) <- c("DimArticleId", "Quantity", "Material", "Dilce", "Kooperace", "Mzdy", "Naklady_pracoviste")
costs_q$DimArticleId <- as.character(costs_q$DimArticleId)
costs_q_active <- costs_q[,c("Quantity", "Material", "Dilce", "Kooperace", "Mzdy", "Naklady_pracoviste")]
mysummary <- cbind.data.frame(
    Statistic = c("Minimum", "1st Quartal", "Median", "Mean", "3rd Quarter", "Maximum")
    , do.call(
        cbind
        , lapply(costs_q_active, summary)
        )
    )

OutputDataSet <- mysummary;', @input_data_1 =N'SELECT *
FROM 
(
    SELECT 
        f.DimArticleId
        , da.ArticleGroupCode
        , dc.NameCze
        , [Value]
    FROM aaa f 
        LEFT OUTER JOIN bbb da
            ON f.Id = da.Id
        LEFT OUTER JOIN ccc dc
            ON f.Id = dc.Id
) AS SourceTable
PIVOT 
    (
        AVG([Value])
        FOR NameCze IN (
                            [Materiál]
                            , [Dílce]
                            , [Kooperace]
                            , [Mzdy]
                            , [Náklady pracovišť]
                            )
    ) AS pvt'; GO
```

I try to change datetype in `WITH RESULT SETS` but it doesn't help me.

Btw: `aaa`, `bbb`, `ccc` is example of my tables.

Comment: I'm very inexperienced at R, but are you just trying to get summary statistics for a sql data set? It seems like a lot of code to do that if so.

Comment: @AnthonyHancock Thank you for a comment. I think you are right, but in my case a try to use R for all calculation. So I wonder why my  code doesn't work like as it would.

Comment: How is your input data set created; what does the code look like? Can you share some sample data?

Comment: @NielsBerglund I add input data set into my edited question.

Comment: @Miška Amy chance you could send some rows from the pivot, with the values. I want to do some tests here.

Comment: @NielsBerglund 
`DimArticleId ArticleGroupCode Materiál Dílce Kooperace Mzdy Náklady pracovišť
68169 V4400 462.51 0 0 12.0706474463451 62.0333223905724
77966 V5020 298.034 0 0 2.90177200588235 25.6227764705882
51797 V5011 146.9655 0 0 1.59594436666667 17.6110755555556
45094 V5033 0 0 0 17.1535469238095 111.00939
24975 V4510 117.7692 0 0 5.2219366091891 15.7297675481053
99588 V4400 3866.850175 0 0 56.8787983550129 338.436011904762
40536 V4420 55.29 0 0 11.6192039309577 51.8262222208902`

Comment: @NielsBerglund I'm sorry for bad formatting, but I'm new here and I don't know how it works.

Comment: Thanks! No probs. I'll have a look.